# getting data from a many to many db relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds user comments and I want to retrieve the last comment made by each user.

Query below should give u an idea of what i am trying to do

```
select comment, comment_id, userId FROM comments_table 
WHERE comment_id in (
   SELECT MAX(comment_id)
   FROM comments_table where userId in (2001, 2002, 2010)
   GROUP BY userId
)
```

Above query works but takes too long especially if there are many userIds.

I need a quicker query statement that accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Use a join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT userid, MAX(comment_id) AS maxcomment
        FROM comments_table
        WHERE userid IN (2001, 2002, 2010)
        GROUP BY userid
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    comments_table b ON 
        a.userid = b.userid AND
        a.maxcomment = b.comment_id
```

The sub-select in this query will only execute once, as opposed to a `WHERE IN` subquery which will execute for each row in the comments table.

Comment: what would i need to add to above query if there is another table called user_details as u that i want to also extract columns u.mainimage and u.fullname maybe using b.user_id= u.user_id

Comment: What table would `user_details` connect link to? The comments table? Users table?

Comment: user_details table primary key is user_id and this is a foreign key in the comments_table.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
         select comment, comment_id, userId FROM          comments_table WHERE userId in (2001, 2002, 2010) order by comment_id desc limit 1
```

Try and see if this query is equivalent with yours
 With an index on the `userid` column, this should perform more than decent

Comment: This will only retrieve one row: *the single most recent comment made from any of the three users*. The O.P. is asking for the most recent comment made by ***each*** of the three users, which means you must perform a group-wise maximum for the comments made by each user.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple:

```
SELECT comment, MAX(comment_id), userId 
FROM comments_table 
WHERE userId IN (2001, 2002, 2010) 
GROUP BY userId;
```

Comment: This solution will pull the most recent `comment_id` per `userid`, but the `comment` field will not be in correct correspondence with the `comment_id`.